# US Chief Justice Roberts' choices of "in conformity with" and "in conformance with" during the swearing in at the Senate

Tags: united-states, senate, supreme-court, terminology, trump-impeachment

US Supreme Court Chief Justice John Roberts used both the phrases *in conformity with* and *in conformance with* within the same minute during a swearing-in process in the senate. This can be heard in [CNN’s video](https://youtu.be/bkTGVIQK4c0?t=97) and I am sure found elsewhere.

Answers to [“Conformity” vs. “conformance”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/77374/217285) In English SE draw some distinction between the usage of the two terms.

Justice Roberts being aware of the historic nature of the event and the importance of words will have chosen them carefully.

Does the choice of the two different phrases in two different context suggest somewhat different meanings and implications?

> at `01:35`    Senators, I attend the Senate in conformity with your notice, for the purpose of joining with you, for the trial of the president of the United States.
>
> at `02:16`   At this time I will administer the oath to all senators in the chamber, in conformance with article 1, section 3, clause 6 of the Constitution and the Senate’s impeachment rules.

Comment: related in English SE: [Is the object in “Eighty-six forty-five.” a proper noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/399555/217285)

Comment: I don't think you're using "historicity" correctly.  I would say "historic nature."  See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/historicity.  Though Merriam Webster's "recent examples on the web" show that you are not alone in employing this new(?) sense: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/historicity

Comment: @phoog yes you are absolutely right. I wanted to find something besides [very historic](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/490515/217285) but I'd read that [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historicity) too quickly while doing an out-the-door post-and-run.

Comment: I think he's using the forms synonymously, but I am not yet confident enough to post an answer.  If I get a chance to watch the video, I might post later.

Comment: Is this really a question about politics? I think it would be more suitable for English.SE, where it is already answered.

Comment: @Philipp as I explained in the question, Justice Roberts will have chosen these words carefully which leads me to think that there is a real difference between the two cases. If there is no political distinction between the chief justice's conforming with the notice and with the constitution, then that is the answer. However if there is a different and the difference phrases reflect it, then *that's* the answer. This is why the general answers in the other SE site can't address this. It's about politics because the chief justice is responding to, and presiding over political processes.

Comment: My guess is that the Chief Justice could refuse to appear and is choosing to conform, whereas he must conform to the swearing requirements to keep the process legal.

Comment: see [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/56250/33008) and https://youtu.be/U2fKJz2rrZo?t=28 It seems that part of my premise is in error; while the event is historic in nature, words are important and the chief justice chose them carefully, they may have been lifted from chief justice Rehnquist rather than newly penned for the occasion by justice Roberts. However the distinction between the two phrases remains.

Comment: There's not much historical about the event, as Trump will not be removed from office. The Senate hearing is a mere formality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> US Chief Justice Roberts' choices of “in conformity with” and “in conformance with” during the swearing in at the Senate.
>   Does the choice of the two different phrases in two different context[s] suggest somewhat different meanings and implications?

Yes, but only marginally so.

[-ity](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ity) a suffix used to form abstract nouns expressing state or condition.
[abstract noun](https://www.lexico.com/definition/abstract_noun) a noun denoting an idea, quality, or state rather than a concrete object.

[-ance](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ance) a suffix used to form nouns [...] from verbs.

Taking the sentences in turn,

> I attend the Senate in conformity with your notice [...].

means *the state or condition of my being here conforms to your notice*.

> [...] I will administer the oath [...], in conformance with [...] the Constitution and the [...] rules.

means *my administering the oath conforms to the Constitution and rules*; the procedure for doing so being specific or "concrete".